# Ping results are not saved in a file

Tags: linux, bash

I am running a simple shell script which initiates the ping and save the result to a txt file.

```
ips=$(cat host.txt)

for ip in $ips
do
ping -c 2 $ip > pingtest.txt  
done
```

However for some reason, there is no output in the text file,I am sure the ip is pinging(I have confirmed with TCP DUMP).

Can someone please help me?

hostfile output is:

```
10.0.0.10

10.0.0.11

172.28.209.43

172.16.84.131
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: @tripleee Not the main issue so wrong duplicate.

Comment: For loop and any form of word splitting can still be used if the whole script doesn't need globbing and `set -f` is set at the beginning of the script. Much less expensive than repetitive builtin calls to read and is not needing temporary array storage.

Comment: @konsolebox How so? What other problems do you see? Do you have a batter duplicate?

Comment: @tripleee I don't care if there's another duplicate. The duplicate you assigned is not necessarily applicable to the problem even though it suggests a better practice. Therefore it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @konsolebox I'd still like to understand what sort of duplicate would be acceptable to you. To me, this is a common FAQ where the OP overwrites their output in each iteration, and the simple fix is to move the redirection after `done`. What else should I look for?

Comment: @tripleee Sorry I must have misread a link. I reverted the close with same duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overwrite the file on every iteration. Do something like this.

```
ips=$(cat host.txt)

for ip in $ips
do
ping -c 2 $ip 
done > pingtest.txt
```

Also as a suggestion, use consistent indentation and avoid word splitting when filename expansion a.k.a globbing is enabled. For example you can use a `while read` loop instead of a `for`.

```
while IFS="" read -r ip
do
    ping -c 2 "$ip"
done <host.txt > pingtest.txt
```